# Spring Data Jpa OneToMany - Exception thrown while trying to save parent and child at same time

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I have a parent table and a child table wherein there's one to many relationship between parent and child - While trying to save parent data which should also save the child data, I am getting an exception - *java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got BINARY*

Here's my code:

```
@Entity(name ="Parent")
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @Generate.....
    @Column
    private int id;
   
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child>();

    simple ... getter and setter ...
}  

@Entity(name ="Child")
public class Child{
    @EmbeddedId
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private ChildCompositeIds id;   

    ... simple getter an setter
}  

@Embeddable
public class ChildCompositeIds implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "child_name")
    private String childName;

    @Column(name = "birth_date",columnDefinition = "DATE")
    private LocalDate birthDate;

    public ChildCompositeIds () {
    }

    public ChildCompositeIds (String childName, LocalDate birthDate) {
        this.childName= childName;
        this.birthDate= birthDate;
    }
    simple ... getter and setter ...
}
```

While saving the parent data, i can see that all the child data in 'ChildCompositeIds' class is populated correctly but still I am getting this exception - *java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got BINARY*.
This has to do something with the field ' birthDate' as i suspect somehow birthdate value , which is one the primary key, is going as null but don't know why - Please assist

Comment: Remvoe  @Column(name = "ID") and also the columndefinition on birthdate

Answer (score 1):

Having `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` is sufficient to cascade the save operation from the parent to the child entities.

The `SQLSyntaxErrorException` means that you tried to save something with a wrong type in a DATE column. Looking at your entities, I would suggest that the birthDate property is most likely the issue. As @Simon Martinelli suggested in his comment, I would remove `columnDefinition = "DATE"` from the `@Column` annotation for starters.

Normally Spring and Hibernate convert dates with no problems if you have set up the database correctly. If the small fix I suggested above doesn't help, we would need more information especially about your database and the table of the child entity.